# Custom separator image used in UITableView disappears when scrolling the UITableView

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I am using a simple UITableView and using separator as a image. When table is loaded initially it looks fine but when user scrolls up and leaves, the separator image disappears. Again when user scrolls down and leaves, lines appears again.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellID=@"Cell"
   MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SwitchCellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UIImageview *aSwitch = [[UIImageview alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"]];
    separator.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,1);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:seperator];

}
..........
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you declare "separator" but you'll want to make sure you initialize and allocate it as a separate instance for each cell.

```
UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 1)];
[cell.contentView addSubView:separator];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use one `separator` instance for all separators in the table?  That won't work because a view can only be added to a single superview.  You should initialize a new separator for each cell in your reuse pool.